# Migrate BigTable table in PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I want to move out of BigTable because it is costly. I have one table of 5GB and want to migrate it to a PostgreSQL database. So far I have found ways to migrate data in BigTable but not out of it, also I don't want to use CloudSQL because this will cost more than keeping using BigTable. Another idea is to export the table as a file and import it with a Python script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation on how to [export data from Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/import-export), but the formats are mainly for reimporting back into Bigtable, so I don't think it will be too helpful for your situation. I think you will probably need to write some custom script to export the data. With only 5GB of data, you probably don't need to use Dataflow and you would probably be fine to do it with a Python script to make it easier even if it isn't as efficient.

I'd recommend doing a full table scan and streaming the results. You can either use Python to write directly to your PostgreSQL DB or can export to some intermediary format, and then import that into PostgreSQL.

```
rows = table.read_rows()
for row in rows:
    // Export to PostgreSQL or to a storage file
```

Check out the docs for more information on [reading from Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reading-data). All of this should work if you can do an offline migration (where you stop your application during the migration,) but if you need to do an online migration, you'd need to keep track of new additions to your database while you're migrating over.